# How to append sku in product title in Magento.?

Tags: php, magento

I want to append sku in product title in Magento using php code. Can anyone please help me on that.

```
<?php 
//set empty title
$title = ''; 
if ($_product = Mage::registry('current_product')) 
{ 
$title = $_product->getName();
$pos = stripos($title);
$title = $this->getTitle();
}
?>
<title><?php echo $title; ?> | test</title>
```

Comment: No this is a different question, I want to append sku in product title like whenever I created a product in Magento it should be automatically append sku in that and showed on UI and btw that is not a straight forward. @04FS

Comment: First: why are you overwriting $title?
To get the SKU:
$sku=$_product->getSku();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the working code for above question.

```
<?php 
//set empty title
$title = ''; 
if ($_product = Mage::registry('current_product')) 
{ 
$title = $_product->getName();
$sku = $_product->getSku();
$pos = stripos($title, $sku);
if($pos === false )
{
//no sku already - append now
$title.= ' - ' . $sku;
}
}
else
{ 
$title = $this->getTitle();
}
?>
<title><?php echo $title; ?> | test</title>
```